# Error converting value \"02:30:40\" to type 'System.TimeOnly'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am working a .net6.0 project (with postgreSql)

I want to save a start time and off time of the office into database.

I did this.

```
public class WorkingDay
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DaysOfWeek Day { get; set; }  // enum

    public OpeningHours OpeningHours { get; set; }

    public bool IsworkingDay { get; set; }
}


public class OpeningHours
{
    public TimeOnly StartTime { get; set; }

    public TimeOnly OffTime { get; set; }

}
```

Now I send the data to create using POSTMAN.

```
{
    "Day" : 1,
    "OpeningHours" : {
        "StartTime":  "02:30:40", 
        "OffTime" :  "02:30:40"
    },
    "IsworkingDay" : false
}
```

I got below error.
`Error converting value \"02:30:40\" to type 'System.TimeOnly'. Path 'OpeningHours.OffTime',`

How can I send the data for `TimeOnly`?

Comment: You will have to write your own JsonConverter for the type: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2021/11/22/dateonly-and-timeonly-support-with-system-text-json/

Comment: Are you using NewtonSoft.Json or System.Text.Json?

Comment: System.Text.Json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` are currently (.NET 6) not supported by `System.Text.Json`. However, they will be implemented in .NET 7, as by [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53539).

There are multiple workarounds for now.

- convert them to `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` and back for serialization.
- switch to .NET 7 preview for development
- copy the .NET 7 implementation to your code (see the [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/69160/files))
- write your own converter (an example of which can be found [in this link](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2021/11/22/dateonly-and-timeonly-support-with-system-text-json/))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `TimeSpan`s (until .NET 7):

```
public class OpeningHours
{
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan OffTime { get; set; }
}
```

When needed later, you can `TimeOnly.FromTimeSpan()`.

Answer (score 0):

JHBonarius provided chock-a-block options list.

However to stay with LTS version of .net this time (.net 6 only awailable) and keep using TimeOnly you need to implement TimeOnlyJsonConverter.

The only thing I want to add to JHBonarius answer - complete example of TimeOnlyJsonConverter for your situation:

```
public class TimeOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<TimeOnly>
{
    private const string Format = "HH:mm:ss.fff";

    public override TimeOnly Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var str = reader.GetString();
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? default : TimeOnly.ParseExact(str, Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TimeOnly value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}

public class OpeningHours
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TimeOnlyJsonConverter))]
    public TimeOnly StartTime { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(TimeOnlyJsonConverter))]
    public TimeOnly OffTime { get; set; }
}
```